# Starting Matlab in Command Line Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, matlab

I would like to start Matlab in its 'shell mode' from the Cygwin terminal. However if I enter

```
matlab
```

the GUI appears. If instead I try

```
matlab -nodesktop
```

Then a new command line opens in another window.

How do I start Matlab so that I can run it in my current Cygwin terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/02/22/launching-matlab-without-the-desktop/), MATLAB works differently depending on whether you're using Windows or Linux.

> `-nodesktop` behaves differently depending if you are on Windows vs Linux or Mac. On Windows we provide a boring Command-Window only interface that lacks the “bells and whistles” of the regular Command Window or the full Desktop.

---

Running with the `-nodesktop` option on **Windows**:

[image]

Running with the `-nodesktop` option on **Linux/Mac**:

[image]

There doesn't appear to be any other way around the issue at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `matlab -nojvm -nodisplay -nosplash`

Source: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html

Comment: Unfortunately it opens a command terminal windows. Impossible to use STDIN and STDOUT